# Show clarity radio buttons based on a condition in Angular

Tags: html, angular8, vmware-clarity

I have a div which has a couple of clr radio buttons wrapped in a .I want to generate the radioButtons based on a boolean value. Following is the code.

```
<div class="clr-col-4">
     <clr-radio-container>
            <label class="display-label">Radio Div</label>
            <clr-radio-wrapper *ngFor="let col of cols">
                 <input type="radio" clrRadio />
                 <label class="display-label" {{col.headerName}}</label>
            </clr-radio-wrapper>
     </clr-radio-container>
</div>
```

I have a variable named enableButton. If the enableButton is true, I want to show the radio button, else I don't want to. Could you please help me how to do this?

Comment: Hello, just wanted to see if my answer has helped you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ngIf` directive. It is an essential thing to have in mind when creating Angular templates.

```
<div class="clr-col-4">
     <clr-radio-container *ngIf="enableButton">
            <label class="display-label">Radio Div</label>
            <clr-radio-wrapper *ngFor="let col of cols">
                 <input type="radio" clrRadio />
                 <label class="display-label" {{col.headerName}}</label>
            </clr-radio-wrapper>
     </clr-radio-container>
</div>
```

I suggest you read the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) to familiarise more with the directive and its other conditional variations like `then`, `else`, etc.